# How to create a pause like effect while counting down in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I'm creating a simple game, where whenever I leave the menu I want a 3 second timer to cover up the screen, while the game is paused. I had imagined I would do something like this

```
protected void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //..//
    for(int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
    {
        spriteBatch(gameFont, i.ToString(), new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2), Color.White);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    //..//
}
```

However, this just pauses at the menu for three seconds, then immediatly puts you in game. You can for a split second see a random number, but not at all a real countdown. What can I do to pause the games running and still draw the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>    Thread.Sleep(1000);
> ```

At the best of times you want to avoid using `Thread.Sleep()` and I can't think of **any-time** you should use it in a **game**.   Games should be running **flat-out and you want to minimise situations where the CPU is blocking or just sleeping**.

> What can I do to pause the games running and still draw the game?

Generally in games (and XNA is no exception), the *draw code* is separate from *state update* mechanics.   This means your `Draw()` should be focused on drawing and nothing else.

*Pausing* can be considered a game **state** and is better served being processed in your game's `Update()`.

Consider adding a state to your game, perhaps:

```
enum States
{
    Initialising,
    InMenu,
    LeavingMenu,
    InGame,
}

States _state;
```

Then in your `Update()` you could work on your state machine, switching from in-menu; to leaving menu; to finally in game:

```
DateTime timeOfEscPressed;
protected virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    switch (_state)
    {
        case States.Initialising:
            break;
        case States.InMenu:
            // *** pseudo-code here ***
            // if ESC pressed then 
            //    _state = States.LeavingMenu
            //    timeOfEscPressed = DateTime.Now;
            break;

        case States.LeavingMenu:
            // stay in this state for 3 seconds
            if ((DateTime.Now - timeOfEscPressed).TotalSeconds >= 3)
            {
                _state = States.InGame;
            }
            break;

        case States.InGame:
            if (menuKeyPressed) // pseudo code
            {
                _state = States.InMenu;
                timeOfEscPressed = DateTime.Now;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Your draw code becomes just that, draw code:

```
protected void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    switch (_state)
    {
        case States.InMenu:
            DrawMenu();
            break;
        case States.LeavingMenu:
            ShowTimer();
            break;
    }
}
```

In this way, you gain the illusion of your game *pausing* but without freezing the update-draw loop.

Comment: Works great! However, I can't seem to make the graphical counter work. And since I can get the formatting properly on this comment, I have to explain that I basically keep track of time the same way you do it in your update method, except that I have a counter variable that counts down every time the if statement is executed. However, this just waits one second then really quickly flashes through the numbers. What can I do to make the counter work?

Comment: @ThatMartinGuy Sounds like you should be basing it on `gameTime.TotalGameTime` and deduct the difference rather than basing it on a counter.  Maybe put that in a new question?